# Intermittent Re-sizing Image Issue

Tags: php, class, image-manipulation, image-resizing

I'm uploading images via stream_copy_to_stream() and then re-sizing them using the class and method below.

This is my resize class: **http://pastebin.com/wtbcbfzv**

I'm using it like so.

```
$resizeObj = new resize('image.jpg');
$resizeObj -> resizeImage(960, 800, 'auto');
$resizeObj -> saveImage('image.jpg', 100);
```

However it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't, it just fails, no errors returned at all. I have the memory limit successfully set at 150M and have gone up to 300M with no such luck. I've also made sure that max_execution_time is set to 0 so there's no worries there.

**Any suggestions on what could be causing this intermittent issue?**

**UPDATE** This is being returned with the only image with the issue and I noticed the height is 6600 and when reduced to i.e. 5500 it works..

`"imagecreatetruecolor() [function.imagecreatetruecolor]: Invalid image dimensions"`

Comment: it's seem like not all image is jpg (it may be named image.jpg, but it is gif file)

Comment: It was scanned like the rest of the images that upload fine, and it sometimes works flawlessly (every so often) but then doesn't most of the time.

Comment: This is being returned with the only image with the issue and I noticed the height is 6600 and when reduced to i.e. 5500 it works..

"imagecreatetruecolor() [function.imagecreatetruecolor]: Invalid image dimensions"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out it was an issue with the host, who has a process that kills anything that will use x% of ram as it is a shared server. All resolved.